# My private messaging doesn't work with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I can't understand why my code (below) doesn't work. The console.log prints the correct socket.id on the server-side, before emitting to the socket. So why isn't the message received?

server-side:

```js
socket.on("connectToUser", function(userName, currentUserName, userID){
        console.log("user wants to connect to: ",userID);
         socket.to(userID).emit("connectNotification", currentUserName);
    });
```

client-side:

```js
socket.on("connectNotification", function(currentUserName){
        console.log("correct user notified");
        $("#connectToBox").append("Hallo");
    });
```

Does the socket.id have to be the original one? I am changing it on connection, like this:

```js
socket.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected', socket.id);
  var id = uuid.v4();
  socket.id = id;
  console.log(socket.id);
```

Comment: I guess yes, it should be the original one, don't manipulate it using `uuid.v4()` and just use what is being returned from your socket and see if it is working

Comment: Let us see how do you create socket var ! I think you should include more about your code because this is not enough for understand what is wrong.

Comment: first you need to check that your client is connected with your server properly

client side : new io.connect("http://localhost:3000 your app url");

Comment: Read this: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room (it will explain why changing `socket.id` will break the ability to contact a particular user using `socket.to(...)`)

Comment: I have to change the id, since I am sending it to a mysql server database. Or else, the id will be different every time the same user logs in.

Comment: @robertklep I've checked out your link, but I can't find the explanation you are talking about? Sure you send the right link?

Comment: @JonasSH _"For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id"_ That is, AFAIK, how `socket.to(...)` is implemented: it sends a message to that room, identified by the _original_ id. If you start using your own id's in `socket.to()`, you're sending messages to rooms that don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `socket.id` after the `connection` event has fired is probably too late, because at that point, `socket.io` has already done some internal housekeeping based on the original id.

If you want to use your own id's, you should use a [middleware function](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn) instead (disclaimer: I'm not overly familiar with the internals of `socket.io`, but some example code I put together seems to work):

```
let server = require('socket.io')(...);

server.use(function(socket, next) {
  socket.id = uuid.v4();
  next();
}).on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.on("connectToUser", function(userName, currentUserName, userID){
    console.log("user wants to connect to: ",userID);
    socket.to(userID).emit("connectNotification", currentUserName);
  });

});
```

Comment: Actually ended up using the original id that is passes to the client on connection. Works perfectly!